# Why won't this specific website run in headless mode?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I use the code below and it works in both headless mode and full browser mode with google.com but with the specific website I want to use....'https://cases.ra.kroll.com/Clovis/Home-DocketInfo' it only works in Full mode. What do I need to change?

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://cases.ra.kroll.com/Clovis/Home-DocketInfo')

print(driver.title)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36")